# ffmpegのsegment_timeオプションが効かないのか

Tags: ffmpeg

ffmpegでWebカメラのライブストリーミングを実装しています。
ライブなのでできる限り遅延を短くしたいものです。
以下のコマンドでsegment_timeとsegment_list_sizeオプションの値を小さくして制御しようと考えています。

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg \
   -f v4l2 -thread_queue_size 1024 -s 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -r 15  \
   -f alsa -thread_queue_size 1024 -i sysdefault:CARD=U0x46d0x994 -ac 2 \
   -c:v libx264 -preset fast -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 640x480 -b:v 1024k -vsync passthrough \
   -c:a aac -b:a 128k -strict -2 \
   -f ssegment -segment_format mpegts -segment_list test.m3u8 \
   -segment_list_type hls -segment_time 10 -reset_timestamps 1 \
   -segment_list_size 3 -segment_list_flags +live \
   -threads 4 out%03d.ts
```

出力された.m3u8ファイルは下記のようになっています、segment_timeオプションが効かない様子です。

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:32
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:17
#EXTINF:16.666667,
out032.ts
#EXTINF:16.733333,
out033.ts
#EXTINF:16.666667,
out034.ts
```

パラメータに何が足りないのでしょうか？
目的はライブの遅延を短くしたいです、他にいい方法があれば教えてくだい。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: オプション`-g 150`でキーフレーム間隔を調整すると改善しませんか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。 オプション`-g 150` は効果がなっかた。オプション`-break_non_keyframes 1` で問題回避しました。

Comment: FFmpegではオプション指定位置も重要です。オプション`-g 150`を`-c:v libx264`より後ろかつ`-c:a aac`より前に指定しても駄目でしょうか。

Comment: これで、キーフレーム間隔調整で分割がうまく出来ました。ご教授ありがとうございます。;-)

Comment: yohjpさん
すみません、オプション `-g` のドキュメントを探していたんでしたが、見つからないので、もしご存知でしらた教えて頂けませんでしょうか。m(__)m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x264エンコードパラメータのGOP長（キーフレーム周期）が原因です。FFmpeg/libx264では[オプション`-g`](https://sites.google.com/site/linuxencoding/x264-ffmpeg-mapping)で指定可能です。

HLSを構成するメディアセグメントファイルでは、各セグメント先頭をキーフレーム(Key-frame)とする必要があります。今回のケースではFFmpegの自動補正により、実質セグメント長を17秒(`#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:17`)として処理したようです。
`-g`デフォルト値は250フレームであり、映像フレームレートに15fps(`-r 15`)を指定していますから、計算される最小セグメント長は250÷15＝16.666667秒、これはm3u8ファイル中の`#EXTINF`タグ出力とも合致します。

HLSセグメント分割長を10秒(`-segment_time 10`)としたい場合は、GOP長もあわせて`-g 150`（15fpsで10秒長）指定が必要です。注意点として、オプション`-g`はlibx264に対するパラメータのため、`-c:v libx264`より後ろ（かつ`-c:a aac`より前）に記述する必要があります。

---

> 目的はライブの遅延を短くしたいです、他にいい方法があれば教えてくだい。

HLSの運用では、セグメント長[10秒が推奨値](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/FrequentlyAskedQuestions/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.html)とされており、それ以外でも[2～15秒程度が一般的](https://www.dash-player.com/blog/2015/04/using-the-optimal-segment-length-for-adaptive-streaming-formats-like-mpeg-dash-hls/)だと思います。

GOP長／セグメント長を短くするほど、ライブの遅延量を小さくできます。一方でGOP長を短くしすぎると、映像エンコード画質が劣化したり、時系列的な画質が不安定になることもありますから、そのあたりのトレードオフを考慮する必要があります。

Answer (score 4):

[segment muxer](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Options-7)の `-break_non_keyframes 1` オプションで問題を回避しました。

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -f v4l2 -thread_queue_size 1024 -s 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -r 30 \
                      -f alsa -thread_queue_size 1024 -i sysdefault:CARD=U0x46d0x994 -ac 2 \
                      -c:v libx264 -preset fast -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 640x480 \
                      -b:v 1024k -quality good -c:a aac -b:a 128k -strict -2 \
                      -f ssegment -segment_format mpegts -segment_list test.m3u8 -break_non_keyframes 1 \
                      -segment_list_type hls -segment_time 10 -segment_list_size 3 -segment_list_flags +live -threads 4 out%03d.ts
```

Comment: `-break_non_keyframes`ではセグメント先頭に非キーフレームを許容するので、映像表示されるまでの遅延削減量は限定的かもしれませんね… とはいえ、セグメント長を短くした分の効果は確実にあると思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます、ご指摘の通りです。